# Find N symbols as unlike to each other as possible, when given matrix of "likeness" of all existing symbols?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to generate a set of symbols (currently bezier curves), and I need them to be as unlike to each other as possible. I have a function that compares two symbols with each other, and therefore I have a big matrix of values of how alike any two given symbols are.

I'm sure that there are better ways than to bruteforce this? I have been looking at various solutions of vaguely related geometric problems ("Find max area polygon given set of points"), but they all seem to be solved geometrically using the pairs of coordinates, which I don't have. Same goes for "Find numbers which sum up to a certain number"; I can't generalize the solutions given there.

I am absolutely at a loss on how to proceed now. It might be possible to somehow position the N symbols in an N-dimensional cube and play with the distances between the points as a n-dimensional polygon, but that's over my head both to formalize and to actually write.

Currently the most I have is finding the N most-alike and least-alike symbols, as long as N is something bruteforceable.

I'd be grateful for any pointers on how to proceed.

Comment: Just to clarify: you can calculate the distance between symbols i and j (and you have in fact already done so, creating an N x N matrix of distances), and now you want to select M (<N) symbols that have the greatest sum of dist(i, j) for all i and j <= M. Is that right?

Comment: @mfripp Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your problem works like this:

Given `N` symbols indexed by `[1, ..., N]`, you can calculate the distance from symbol `i` to symbol `j` using a distance function `dist(i, j)`. Your goal is to choose a subset of `M` symbols, where `M <= N`, that maximize `sum(dist(i, j) for i in range(M) for j in range(i))`. (Note: I assume that `dist(i, i) == 0` and `dist(i, j) = dist(j, i)`, so we only consider pairs with `i < j`.)

I don't know if there's a direct way to solve this (you could try asking on math.stackexchange.com), but this can be written as an optimization problem with binary variables, roughly like this:

```
decision variables: 
# whether to include symbol i
x[i] (binary, i in range(N))

objective:
maximize sum(x[i]*x[j]*dist(i, j) for i in range(M) for j in range(i))

constraint:
sum(x[i] for i in range(N)) == M
```

This version has a quadratic objective function, and not every solver can handle that. However, you can also write it as a linear programming problem with binary variables:

```
decision variables: 
# whether to include symbol i
x[i] (binary, i in range(N))
# whether both symbol i and j are included
xx[i, j] (i in range(N), j in range(i))

objective
maximize sum(xx[i, j]*dist(i, j) for i in range(M) for j in range(i))

constraints: 
sum(x[i] for i in range(N)) == M
xx[i, j] <= x[i], (i in range(N), j in range(i))
xx[i, j] <= x[j], (i in range(N), j in range(i))
```

You can implement either of the problems above in a python-based optimization package and then have that package use a standard mixed-integer solver to find the answer. The pulp or pyomo packages would be good choices for this. In my experience, pulp is easier to get started with, but pyomo is better for large, standardized problems where you may run the same model with different data.

By default, I think pulp uses the glpk solver, which cannot handle quadratic problems. So if you use the quadratic form, you will also need to install a solver that can handle quadratic integer problems. If your problem is small, you should be able to use CBC or the community version of gurobi or cplex as the solver. Even if you use the linear form, you may want to use cplex or gurobi as the solver, because they are much faster than glpk and cbc.

Here's an example of solving the linear form of this model using the pulp package (you'll need to use `pip install pulp` to get that package):

```
from pulp import *

def dist(i, j):
    # use simple distance for testing
    return abs(i - j)

N = 20  # number of symbols
M = 10  # number of symbols to select

# create problem object
prob = LpProblem("Greatest Distance Problem", LpMaximize)

# define decision variables
include = LpVariable.dicts("Include", range(N), 0, 1, LpInteger)
include_both = LpVariable.dicts("Include Both", combination(range(N), 2))

# add objective function
prob += (
    lpSum([include_both[i, j]*dist(i, j) for i, j in combination(range(N), 2)]), 
    "Total Distance"
)

# define constraints
prob += (
    lpSum(include[i] for i in range(N)) == M,
    "Select M symbols"
)
for i, j in combination(range(N), 2):
    prob += (include_both[i, j] <= include[i], "")
    prob += (include_both[i, j] <= include[j], "")

prob.solve()

print "Status: {}".format(LpStatus[prob.status])
print "Included: {}".format([i for i in range(N) if value(include[i]) == 1])
```

Comment: Thank you, you explained my problem much better than I myself have. Looking right now through what you have suggested, really glad to have something to get started with.